# jsonb_array_elements get element position

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a `JSONB` column containing multiple rows.
Each row holds a `JSON` array.

Now I need to put this into rows but I need the position of the elements as well.

e.g.

```
select *
from (
   select jsonb_array_elements("values"::jsonb) from "myData"
) as x;
```

Gives me all elements from all arrays of all rows.

## How can I get the array index as well?

```
data                        
----------------------------
{ text: "Hello" } | 0 <-- first array element from first row
{ text: "World" } | 1 <-- second array element from first row
{ text: "Hallo" } | 0 <-- first array element from second row
{ text: "Welt!" } | 1 <-- second array element from second row
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a lateral join and [`with ordinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```
select *
from (
    select t.* 
    from "myData", jsonb_array_elements("values") with ordinality as t(data, idx)
) as x;
```

If `"values"` is already a `jsonb` column there is no need to cast it to `jsbon`

Comment: Great! Do you know how i can add an alias to that? I use that in a subquery and get "subquery in FROM must have an alias"